# Empty Password Field Enables Successful LDAP Bind

Tags: php, binding, ldap, bind

I'm currently working on my first LDAP script in PHP with 2 binds.
The first bind seems to be working alright, in that I am getting a return of the results after the successful bind to the server for querying. 
The second bind, though, which uses the distinguishedName result from the initial bind, is giving me some problems. 
When that second bind is attempted, it will allow an empty password field to bind with the distinguishedName.
However, when an incorrect password is entered, it will correctly not bind.
Why are the empty entries binding, in this case?  Thanks for any leads.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
//begin set parameters
$host = "*****";
$port = "3268";
$rdnUsername = "*****";//for accessing server
$rdnPassword = "*****";//for accessing server


$_connect = ldap_connect($host);
if (! $_connect) {
    die ('no connection');
}

if (isset($rdnUsername) && isset($rdnPassword)) {
    $args [] = $_connect;
    $args [] = $rdnUsername;
    $args [] = $rdnPassword;
}
if ( ! call_user_func_array ( 'ldap_bind', $args ) ) {
    die (
        sprintf('Could not bind to server %s. Returned Error was: [%s] %s',$host,ldap_errno($_connect),ldap_error($_connect))
    );
}

if (! isset($filter)) {
    $filter = "(userPrincipalName=".$_POST['username']."@school.edu)";
}

$trimmerdUsername = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_@\.]/', '', $_POST['username']));

$filter = str_replace($_POST['username'], $trimmerdUsername, $filter);

$attributes = array("name", "telephonenumber", "mail", "userprincipalname");
$ldap_dn = "dc=tcw,dc=net,dc=tceo,dc=edu";

$_ldapresults = ldap_search($_connect, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attributes, 0, 0, 10 ) or exit("Unable to search");

if (! $_ldapresults) {
    die ('No user with that information found');
}
if (1 > ldap_count_entries($_connect, $_ldapresults)) {
    die ('No user with that information found');
}

if (1 < ldap_count_entries($_connect, $_ldapresults )) {
    die ('More than one user found with that information');
}

$_results = ldap_get_entries($_connect, $_ldapresults);
if (false === $_results) {
    die ('no result set found');
}

ldap_free_result ( $_ldapresults );
$distinguishedName = $_results[0]['dn'];

$userPrincipalName = $_results[0]["userprincipalname"][0];
print "<pre>";
print_r ($_results);
print "</pre>";
echo "<br>userPrincipalName is: ".$userPrincipalName."<br>";
echo "<br>distinguishedName is: ".$distinguishedName."<br>";


$password = $_POST['password'];
$link_id = @ldap_bind($_connect, $distinguishedName, $password);

//if (false === $link_id) {
if ($link_id === false) {   
    die ('BIND failed');
}else{
    echo "<br>success!<br>";    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Without a password ldap binds anonymously.

That's defined in the protocol and it is required by the application to not allow binding with an empty password.

That is also documented on the ldap_bind documentation of PHP (http://php.net/ldap_bind)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid connecting to the LDAP server anonymously from application because you can not rely on server configuration. However, if you have access to the server, you can control the access to the entries by limiting the access. Add these lines in **slapd.conf**

> access to * by anonymous auth

To learn more about access control: https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html